# jQuery Animation is Jumping

Tags: jquery

Can anybody help me with this?

I'm animating this as a horizontal nav. See my jsFiddle coding:

```
 <ul>
    <li >Item 1</li>
    <li >Item 1</li>                        
    <li >Item 1</li>                    
 </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k6YT8/

When you move the mouse too quickly over the list items, they get jumpy and sometimes it breaks into 2 or 3 lines.

Please look at my jQuery and let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/k6YT8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set proper `width` of your `ul` -

```
ul {
    display: block; clear: both;
    width:900px; 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/KVH92/)

Comment: you could also throw a `.stop()` or two in there to prevent the animation from queuing like crazy.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the stop() method

```
$('ul li').hover(
        function() {
            //mousein action
            $('ul li').stop(true, true);
            $('ul li.active').animate({
                width:'60'
            },250, function(){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            });
            $(this).addClass('active').animate({
                width:'360'
            },250, function(){
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        },
        function () {
            //mouseout action

        }
    );
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/k6YT8/2/

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you call a function, every time, mouse hovers an element. This way you might produce a long queue of functions which may eventually break your animation in various ways. To prevent this, you can use `stop()` method, which **Stops the currently-running animation on the matched elements.**
Optionally you can call it with 2 boolean parameters:

```
.stop( [ clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )
```

Where clearQueue removes all animations from queue, if set to true and jupToEnd indicates, whether currently active animation should end immediately or not. So calling this, **before any new animation**:

```
.stop(true,true)
```

makes it sure, that **all animations are stopped, queue reset and it does it instantly**.
[Read more here!](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)